# How to make Apache 2 stop asking for a password for an SSL certificate?

Tags: apache2, ssl

I just added an SSL certificate to Apache. The problem is that Apache runs on system startup and after my server turns on, Apache runs but doesn't run. I put in the IP address of my computer and my browser just keeps trying to connect. I see a spinning circle.

Then I get on my server, kill all Apache-related processes, and run `sudo service apache2 restart`. Because of the `sudo` I am prompted for my super-user password, but after I put it in, Apache asks for the password for the .key file. I put it in and then Apache works fine. The SSL even works.

So why does Apache not work until I restart it? Is it because it wants me to put in the password every startup? If so, how do I do that on my Xubuntu server? Can I make it so I won't have to put it in every time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that the private key for your SSL certificate is password-protected. To test whether this is really the case, examine the beginning of your keyfile using the command `head -3 your.key`. This private key is encrypted:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,C251E8A1254B933D763703EE1C364AB7
```

This file is not encrypted:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAvbeWtO9nQP4cFFuhGrOM/WQ73oTQHU7mzZB9CaA3R2iwjDNz
wwlDtT9tfo0tCC2ib9STfeM6AYrdI3wauzCu7AV4CFGSMP3HLX8DJuk8zzbdQHHv
```

To remove the password from a RSA private key, use the following command:

```
umask 077
mv your.key old-with-pass.key
openssl rsa -in old-with-pass.key -out your.key
```

The `umask 077` command is necessary to ensure that the new key is not created with overly relaxed permissions. Alternatively, you can manually change the mode of the file with `chmod 400 new.key`. Depending on the location of the key, you might have to prefix the `openssl`, `mv` and `chmod` commands with `sudo`.

Comment: Thank you. My key file was encrypted and this fixed it the first time. Thank you so much. I never would have figured that out.

Comment: I run openssl rsa.. it give errors, then I used sudo to solve it

Answer (score 6):

Answer on [http://serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/a/160835) by @JamesSneeringer.

> I've been guilty of removing the passphrase from my own key files in
>   the past, because it's the simplest solution, but security-wise, it's
>   not the best idea. An alternative is to feed the passphrase to Apache.
>   You can do this with the [`SSLPassPhraseDialog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslpassphrasedialog) option in your
>   `httpd.conf` (or another file that it includes).
>
> If you only have one SSL site on your server, the simplest form of
>   this would be:
>
> ```
> # either of these will work
> SSLPassPhraseDialog |/path/to/passphrase-script
> SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/path/to/passphrase-script
> ```
>
> You would then create a very simple script called
>   `/path/to/passphrase-script` that contains something like the
>   following:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> echo "put the passphrase here"
> ```
>
> When starting up, Apache will take the output of this script and use
>   it as the passphrase for your SSL key. If you have multiple SSL sites,
>   [`SSLPassPhraseDialog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslpassphrasedialog) has additional ways in which it can be
>   used, so you can either have a single script for all of your keys, or
>   a separate script for each, or however you want to do it.

Comment: Is it a good idea to have the password stored in a script in plain text?

Comment: I think it is even worse having so password! So i would rether than go with the bad solution than a very bad solution :D